# ORA-15081: failed to submit an I/O operation to a disk

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recovery, corruption, rman

I have a test environment for Oracle single instance on ASM 11.2.0.3.

I have restored database from tape and during the recovery, the system crashed by some I/O error.

I restarted the server, mounted the database and run validate on archivelog(thinking that the blocks in this archivelog may be corrupted)

```
RMAN> validate archivelog sequence=2994;

RMAN-03009: failure of validate command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 02/25/2014 12:24:13
ORA-19501: read error on file "+DATA01/crimesys/archivelog/2014_02_24/thread_1_seq_2994.294.8
ORA-15081: failed to submit an I/O operation to a disk
ORA-15081: failed to submit an I/O operation to a disk
```

And the system crushed again.

Note:  Other validates are successful just this archivelog causes the system crash.

Details:

--Asm disk

```
ls -la /dev/oracleasm/asm_disk1
brw-rw---- 1 grid asmdba 253, 2 Feb 25 13:13 /dev/oracleasm/asm_disk1
```

--Trace info

```
more /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/crimesys/crimesys/trace/crimesys_ora_2696.

WARNING: Read Failed. group:1 disk:0 AU:114682 offset:512 size:1048064
path:/dev/oracleasm/asm_disk1
         incarnation:0xe968a075 asynchronous result:'I/O error'
         subsys:System iop:0x7fd93c64b680 bufp:0x7fd93b64e000 osderr:0x0 osderr1:0x0
WARNING: failed to read mirror side 1 of virtual extent 13 logical extent 0 of file 294 in gr
oup [1.353915012] from disk DATA01_0000  allocation unit 114682 reason error; if possible, wi
ll try another mirror side
```

--Also when I check the disk of ASM it is successful.

```
SQL> alter diskgroup data01 check 

NOTE: starting check of diskgroup DATA01
Tue Feb 25 13:36:59 2014
GMON checking disk 0 for group 1 at 5 for pid 18, osid 2181
SUCCESS: check of diskgroup DATA01 found no errors
SUCCESS: alter diskgroup data01 check
```

How to solve? Is the virtual block corrupted? How to check? 
Please help.

Comment: Disk permissions? 660 looks like it might cause problems. See http://deryaoktay.wordpress.com/tag/ora-15081/

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have changed permissions but still not working. Maybe there is the problem with virtual disk, but don't know how to check.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using multi-path make sure that your O.S. does not point to the file system instead of the disk groups. 
  it happened to me 2 times after box reboot.

---

**This is to answer your question:**

```
SQL> set pagesize 800
SQL> select name, label, path from v$asm_disk;
NAME                           LABEL
------------------------------ -------------------------------
PATH

DGER_0000    /dev/oracleasm/disks/DSK5

DGSTBY_0000 /dev/oracleasm/disks/DSKPATHY
```

---

**run the follwing command :**

```
 /etc/init.d/oracleasm querydisk -d <your disk here>
```

post the output !

Comment: It is not using multi-path. How to check what you said? ("O.S. does not point to the file system instead of the disk groups")

Comment: It returns 
DATA01_0000 |                                             /dev/oracleasm/asm_disk1

Comment: `-bash: /etc/init.d/oracleasm: No such file or directory`

Comment: I am using UDEV rules not asmlib, as I remember `/etc/init.d/oracleasm` exists when using asmlib,isn't it?

Comment: Not sure how to deal with it now !! but take a look at this link it might help you start your troubleshhoting http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/udev-scsi-rules-configuration-in-oracle-linux-5-and-6.php